# Independent binary variable (frequency) and continuous response variable - lmm

Tags: r

I've spent a lot of time searching for a solution but not successfully. For that reason I decided to post my problem or question here hoping somebody of you can help me.

I want to find out which variables are influencing the travel distance of two animals (same species).

The response variable is distance moved (in meters). In total I have 66 tracking sessions for both animals.

The independent variables are: temperature, rainfall, offspring (yes = 1, no = 0), observation period (in minutes) and activity.

I looked at the animals (one day - one animal) every 15 minutes and noted the state of activity (active = 1 or inactive = 0). For that reason my data table consists around 1800 points and the same amount of activity records.

Then I created a table with following columns:

```
Animal, Tracking-Session, rainfall, offspring, observation period, active, inactive, distance
```

The two columns `active` and `inactive` contain the sum of active (inactive) records per tracking session.

For example in tracking-session 1 the animal A was 30 times active and 11 inactive and moved 6000 meters during that tracking session.

I thought I could do my analysis with this table using the command `cbind()` to make one column for activity out of the two columns with "inactive" and "active". But this does not work, I get:

```
Error in lme4::lFormula(formula = distance~ (1 | animal) + activity + offspring + ...
  rank of X = 12 < ncol(X) = 13
```

I want to include the second animal as a random factor to get an output valid for the whole "population" (which only consits of two animals in that case).

How can I fit a linear mixed model to this data or the first question is: how my data table has to look like to do such analysis?

I started running a linear mixed model with my original data table consisting of 1800 rows but the outcome was not convincing. And I don't know if this table was built up correctly for this task. Because I have only 60 tracking sessions and for that reason only 60 resulting travel distances, but 1800 records of activity (each 15 minutes - active or inactive). I don't know how to handle this situation the only possibility for me to overcome this problem was to copy the travel distace (which is the result of all points watched per day) and assign it to each single point of that tracking session.

The same is for rainfall and temperature because these conditions were only measured once a day I had to copy the value for each single point taken on the same day.
Is this correct or better can R handle such tables (like in the picture)? Or is it better to create a table with one row for each day (as I describe above)?
If the the second table (the one with one row per tracking session) is the better choice, how has it be transformed that R can use it?

Hopefully you can follow my explanations (I tried to explain it as detailed as possible) and anyone can help me!

Thanks in advance!
Iris

Comment: `cbind` doesn't produce one column. There are probably several ways to aggregate the activity data into one variable. E.g., you could calculate `active/(active+inactive)`.

Comment: thanks for that comment - I will use active time per day (acive/(acive+inactive)

Comment: but if I do so... the activity is a proportion (active time/observation time) does R treat proportions differently? Or can I use the value of the proportion like any other numeric value?

Comment: `lme4` can handle proportions as a predictor just fine. If it makes sense to assume a linear relationship with a proportion I cannot tell you without (a) your data and/or (b) a better understanding of the science. However, that was only intended as an example. How you combine those variables into one variable is up to you.

Comment: In principle you should be able to use logistic regression to handle this problem (with your original binary response variable and `glmer(...,family="binomial")`.  It is also plausible to model it as binomial (aggregating by day as you have done), although in this case you may want to allow for overdispersion.  This is turning into a question that's more suited for CrossValidated ...

Comment: To answer your other question; if you have *only* covariates per day (no predictors of interest vary within day), then you might as well aggregate.  If you have covariates that vary at different levels (i.e. per observation and per day), then you do indeed want to copy them so you have the same values repeated for each observation within a day.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I now fitted a model for the activity (I calculated active Points/total Points ~ temp+rain+.., weights=total points, family = binomial). Is this ok so? the second question is at which hour after sunset the animals are more active. I thought I can do this in the same model but now i think i have to create a second model. Am I right?